# fullCalendar eventClick handler does not work if editable false

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

The jQuery fullCalendar plugin seems to have a problem in the [editable mode](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/editable/) in certain cases. If the [eventClick handler](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/) is set and editable is true, than the eventClick function will not work, only the eventDrop function. If editable is set to false, the eventDrop function does not work (as expected), but the eventClick function does. I am not sure where the problem is, is it possible to use the eventClick and eventDrop handler while editable is true? Has someone encountered a similar problem while using the plugin?

> ```
> $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>   ..
>   editable:true,
>   eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
>     .. // only called if editable is false (?)
>   },
>   eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {
>     .. // only called if editable is true (correct)
>   }
> ```

Comment: Hi I'm not getting this behaviour, I have editable: true and an eventClick handler which is firing no problem.  What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: The site which produces the error uses jQuery 1.3.2. A simple demo site with jQuery 1.5.2 seems to be ok. Maybe the jQuery version is the problem. Won't you post your comment as an answer? It may be the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I thought the jQuery version has something to do with it. Further testing did not confirm this hypothesis. It turns out that the click handler works only if you disable resizing with `disableResizing:true`, i.e. if editable is true (`editable:true`) then the click event is only triggered if resizing is disabled (`disableResizing:true`). Maybe the Resize and Click events influence each other somehow..

Comment: Again, not getting this on my project, I'm using resizing and click events at the same time. FYI my jquery is 1.6.2 but maybe its something else, hard to know.  Just thought I would add this comment so others don't assume you can't do this.

Comment: I am not sure where the exact source of the error is, it is a weird error. Javascript bugs can be very strange and annoying. In smaller example projects it seems to work, independent from the jQuery version. In the full project somehow this weird error occurs, and I was only able to avoid it by setting disable:Resizing to true. It is only a workaround, I would prefer a better, cleaner solution.

Comment: disbleResizing is depricated now http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/removed/disableResizing/ Just for the record

Answer (score 1):

It seems from the above that using jQuery 1.3.2 was causing this problem and a more recent version of jQuery will fix this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to be the cause, but thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the **editable: true** option and instead I fixed it by installing the jQuery UI modules:

- Draggable (the Droppable module is not required)
- Resizable