# Rails 3 Full Calendar- unable to update events

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, fullcalendar

Relatively new to Jquery and Rails 3. I have implemented full calendar into my site and all works ok apart from actually updating my Events model via the full calendar interface. From what iunderstand I should be able to drag and drop a calendar entry to another day and it will update the Events model and leave the appointment in its new day upon a refresh. This however does not happen. has anyone had similar issues with this? the code for this action looks like this

```
function updateEvent(the_event) {
$.update(
  "/events/" + the_event.id,
  { event: { title: the_event.title,
             starts_at: "" + the_event.start,
             ends_at: "" + the_event.end,
             description: the_event.description
           }
  },
  function (reponse) { alert('successfully updated task.'); }
);
```

};

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with [editing events in the fullCalendar plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038062/fullcalendar-eventclick-handler-does-not-work-if-editable-false). In my case it had to do with the parameters `editable` and `disableResizing`. You have to implement the [eventDrop](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/) handler for the drag and drop functionality. The parameters dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay contain the time difference between old and new date:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    editable: true,
    eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {
      $.ajax({
         type:"PUT",
         url: "/events/"+event.id,
         data: "minute_delta="+minuteDelta+"&day_delta="+dayDelta,
         ..
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, just a question regarding the placement of this code. Does this go in the calendar.js or fullcalendar.js?

Comment: I placed it in the calendar.js last night and was getting all kinds of errors, mainly the calendar would not load and then error messages regarding the header:

Comment: ok so i have put the code in calendar.js and when i drag the event into a new day/time it just goes back to where it originally was. Any ideas?